# How To Re-Write AJAX calls with JQuery $.Deferred?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Would someone please show me how to re-write this AJAX call utilizing JQuery $.Deferred?  Thank you very much.

The old way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/CountryIP/?TYPE=JSON",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data,textStatus){
       var userData = $.parseJSON(data);
       alert(userData.regionCode);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to accomplish here. You'll get more answers if you explain what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simply:

```
$.ajax({ url: "/CountryIP/?TYPE=JSON", type: "GET" }).then(function(data,textStatus){
    var userData = $.parseJSON(data); alert(userData.regionCode); 
});
```